Why does cirq produce a non-positive semidefinite density matrix doing quantum tomography?
While doing quantum tomography in cirq, I ended up getting a density matrix which is not positive semi-definite. Why is this so? Here's the code I used:
import cirq
from cirq.experiments import state_tomography
q0, q1, q2 = cirq.LineQubit.range(3)
circuit = cirq.Circuit(
    cirq.CNOT(q0,q1),         
    cirq.CNOT(q0, q2)    
)
simulator = cirq.Simulator()

results = state_tomography(
    sampler=simulator,
    qubits=[q0, q1],
    circuit=circuit,
    repetitions=5000
)
density_matrix = results.data
print("Reconstructed Density Matrix:")
print(density_matrix)
eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eigh(density_matrix)
print(eigenvalues)


Can you provide your code so that we can identify the issue?

Hi, I have edited the question including the code. Thanks in advance

related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21429/55

I am wondering how can make the necessary edits in the code to incorporate this. Could you please help me with this? Is it saying that I should increase the number of runs? I didn't actually understood that
