Is there a theoretical method to achieve a positive semi-definite density matrix in QST?
The problem of encountering negative eigenvalues in the density matrix during Quantum State Tomography (QST) is well-explained in this Quantum Computing Stack Exchange post.
However, I am seeking clarification on applying this concept to a 10-qubit code and performing QST on a 3-qubit subsystem of it. My primary objective is to compute the entropy, but the negative eigenvalues are causing divergence in my calculations.
When I execute QST using the following code in Cirq, I end up with a density matrix that has negative eigenvalues. Is there a theoretical method ensuring that QST results in a positive semi-definite density matrix?
cirq.experiments.state_tomography(
sampler: 'cirq.Sampler',
qubits: Sequence['cirq.Qid'],
circuit: 'cirq.Circuit',
repetitions: int = 1000,
prerotations: Optional[Sequence[Tuple[float, float]]] = None,

)

does this answer your question? https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21429/55

@MarkusHeinrich Thank you very much. That exactly answers my question. But I did'nt find a proper answer on how to mitigate this. Ultimately I need to find the entropy, but these negative values are causing serious problems

In that case, I encourage you to edit your post to reflect that you are aware of the problem but that you're looking for a way to mitigate this for your precise use case (don't hesitate to give details on your use case). Once done, the post could be reopened!

the short answer to the new version of the question is: don't use linear state tomography. Approaches like maximum likelihood tomography are for example ensured to give estimates that are proper density matrices (though of course every method has its own pros and cons). Or better yet, if the goal is estimating the entropy, don't pass through state tomography at all, but instead build directly an estimator for the entropy

Thank you! The Maximum Likelihood Tomography worked
